# Divide square with circular hole in 3 equal parts

Tags: geometry

3 friends want to share a square donut. How should they cut it?

[Here](https://imgur.com/a/DMnZU) you can find:

1. A clear visual representation of the problem, as in this is my representation of a squared taurus. The donut is of equal thickness and you can assume that because of the toppings your friends aren't going to be happy if you cut sideways.
2. Thus this can be handled as a 2D problem with area instead of volume.
3. My best solution which still has an easy construction.

Comment: With a knife, presumably.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri  you just made me laugh out loud 

Comment: Parts of different shape but equal area would be acceptable?

Comment: @Anaedonist yes, trying to find an optimal way of cutting in the sense of “easy to know where to cut”

Comment: Cut the square in half, cut one half in half again, give one of the quarters to each friend.  After all, you did all the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the aim is parts of equal area, then a solution is to cut a square portion in the middle (length side $l$): this will leave a square donut with a square opening, to be then cut in two.
In order for the parts to have equal area, the following equation should hold (area of central cut square minus hole area, equal to half the resulting square donut with square opening):
$$ l^2 - 2\pi r^2 = \frac {1}{2}(L^2 - l^2)$$ where $r$ is the radius of the round hole, $L$ the side length of your donut, $l$ the side of the square to be cut in the middle (its center coinciding with the hole center).
The length $l$ turns out to equal $$ \sqrt{\frac{L^2}{3}+\frac{2}{3} \pi r^2} $$ hoping that $r$ is not too large..

In practice, one could also pragmatically cut in four pieces along the diagonals, and serve one part each. Then one can divide the remaining in three parts: being smaller, any error will be reduced.
Even better, cut the excess of a inscribed circumference in the original square: you get a classic donut easy to divide in three exactly. Then you are left with the four corner trimmings: each gets one, and the last is so small, that you are below your measuring uncertainty and the error is negligible.

Comment: Thanks! Now we can finally start eating our hipster doughnuts ☺️

Comment: Neat answer, but I do not think it is actually correct, because this is a 3D problem. You have divided the plan of the donut into three equal areas, but almost certainly the central piece will be a smaller piece of donut, because it is thinner on average. The real problem with the question is that the shape of a "square donut" is undefined: how do the corners extend the shape of the torus? So I think the answer is that there can be no strategy, short of weighing, or an approximation method such as you have mentioned.

Comment: @Brian Chandler, indeed, the (rather strong, possibly unrealistic) assumption was clearly done, that the thickness is constant, and that the hole is cylindric.